# Problem with counters

Tags: beamer, counters

I want to make a presentation with certain tasks, but since there are certain problems with using `enumitem` with `beamer`, I decided to make it myself, so I have this example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcounter{tasknumber}
\stepcounter{tasknumber}
\newcounter{taskletter}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tasknumber}
\resetcounteronoverlays{taskletter}

\newcommand{\task}[1][ ]
{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{+}}{
        \stepcounter{tasknumber}\setcounter{taskletter}{0}}{} %<- why this doesn't work?
        Task \thetasknumber.
}

\newcommand{\taskl}
{
    \stepcounter{taskletter}
    \alph{taskletter})
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\task}
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
    \end{frame}
    %\setcounter{taskletter}{0}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\task[+]}
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, I want to get first frame for first task with a), b) and c), and second frame for second task with a) b) and c) as well, but I get d), e) and f) on second frame. I wouldn't like adding `\setcounter{taskletter}{0}` after every frame.

Comment: My guess is that a frame's title actually is typeset *after* a frame's body… then the stepping is done too late

Comment: @cmhughes even when I delete `\resetcounteronoverlays`, I get the same problem

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setcounter{taskletter}{0}}` in the preamble seems to reset the counter for each frame. You may also want to add a `%` to the end of the line containing `\ifthenelse` to avoid excess whitespace on Tasks 2-n.

Comment: @MikeRenfro well, what if i have task 1 on frame 1, and task 1 on frame 2 again, but a), b) and c) on frame one, and d), e) and f) on frame 2...

Comment: You may be able to make two types of custom frames, and reset taskletter on one of them, but I don't have a working example for that yet.

Answer (score 3):

You should put `\frametitle` inside `\task` instead of the reverse.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\newcounter{tasknumber}
\stepcounter{tasknumber}
\newcounter{taskletter}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tasknumber}
\resetcounteronoverlays{taskletter}

\newcommand{\task}[1][ ]
{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{+}}{
        \stepcounter{tasknumber}\setcounter{taskletter}{0}}{} %<- why this doesn't work?
        \frametitle{Task \thetasknumber.}
}

\newcommand{\taskl}
{
    \stepcounter{taskletter}
    \alph{taskletter})
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \task
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
    \end{frame}
    %\setcounter{taskletter}{0}
    \begin{frame}
        \task[+]
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
        \taskl ...
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```